# What unit of measure does System.Windows.Media.Geometry.GetArea() uses?

Tags: .net

I'm working on a program that does most of its measurements in square inches. When I plot out my points and run the path.getarea method I get 5400000.0402331352. I know that the desired value is 5.400 (sq in).

Does anyone know the unit of measure being used by `System.Windows.Media.Geometry`? Also is there any way to change this?

Comment: When you plot your points, are you 100% positive that they are in inches as well? I believe that the Geometry should be unitless. It looks like the points are in milli-inches (if there is such a thing...)

Answer (score 0):

If 5400000 sq units represents 5.4 sq in then 5400000/5.4 represents 1 sq in. So the units of linear measurement are sqrt(5400000/5.4) per inch, or 0.001 inches *for your case*.

I don't know how to change that, but you can easily scale the result. I suspect the 0.0402331352 is due to cumulative errors.

Comment: Right the input is in mils (.001), but what I'm really hoping to find is if there's a way to change this automatically. I'm trying to avoid manipulating these numbers since I know there is a bit of a fudge factor in the GetArea method.